# metodo para eliminar vocales recursivamente en una cadena, pero se me esta desbordando. java

Tags: java

**Método para eliminar vocales recursivamente en una cadena, pero se me esta desbordando. java**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cad="santi";     
    char[] array = cad.toCharArray();   
    array=sacarConsonantes(0 ,' ', array);  
    String string = String.valueOf(array);
    System.out.println(string);               
}   
public static char[] sacarConsonantes(int i, char aux, char array[]) {  
    if(i==array.length-1) {
        return array;
    }
    else {    
        aux=array[i];
        if(aux == 'a'||aux == 'e'||aux == 'i'||aux == 'o'||aux == 'u'
                ||aux == 'A'||aux == 'E'||aux == 'I'||aux == 'O'||aux == 'U') {
            array[i]=' '; 
            return sacarConsonantes(i++, aux=' ', array);
        }
        else {
        return sacarConsonantes(i++, aux=' ', array);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: proba hacer i+1 en lugar de i++ y fijate que pasa.. igual siempre estas mandando en aux un espacio, con lo cual no se que sentido tiene eso...

Comment: Efectivamente ese es el problema. Como esta usando `i++` esta entrando el valor original de i en la llamada recursiva. `i+1` estaría bien. `++i` también pero `i+1` es mejor.

Comment: el aux con el espacio es para dejar un espacio en la cadena cada vez que haya una vocal

Comment: si funciona con i+1 pero solo borra la primera vocal de la cadena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en hacer un post incremento `i++`. El valor de la variable `i` se incrementará hasta que haya salido de su ámbito.  La solución es usar un preincremento `++i` (En el preincremento la variable incrementa su valor en el mismo momento) o una expresión de suma `i + 1`.

Hay otro error en la condición base `if (i == array.length - 1)`, eso hace que se ignore el último caracter de la cadena. Debe ser: `if (i == array.length)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String cad = "santi";
            char[] array = cad.toCharArray();
            array = sacarConsonantes(0, ' ', array);
            String string = String.valueOf(array);
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    
        public static char[] sacarConsonantes(int i, char aux, char[] array) {
            if (i == array.length) {
                return array;
            } else {
                aux = array[i];
                if (aux == 'a' || aux == 'e' || aux == 'i' || aux == 'o' || aux == 'u'
                        || aux == 'A' || aux == 'E' || aux == 'I' || aux == 'O' || aux == 'U') {
                    array[i] = ' ';
                    return sacarConsonantes(++i, aux = ' ', array);
                } else {
                    return sacarConsonantes(++i, aux = ' ', array);
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**Actualización:**

Removiendo la variable `char aux` innecesaria y simplificando el return de la llamada recursiva:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cad = "santi";
        char[] array = cad.toCharArray();
        array = sacarConsonantes(0, array);
        String string = String.valueOf(array);
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public static char[] sacarConsonantes(int i, char[] array) {
        if (i == array.length) {
            return array;
        } else {
            char aux = array[i];
            if (aux == 'a' || aux == 'e' || aux == 'i' || aux == 'o' || aux == 'u'
                    || aux == 'A' || aux == 'E' || aux == 'I' || aux == 'O' || aux == 'U') {
                array[i] = ' ';
            }
            return sacarConsonantes(++i, array);
        }
    }
```

Comment: aux es una variable sin sentido en la llamada.. no cumple ninguna funcion...

Comment: valdria explicar un poco mas como funciona un post incremento y un pre incremento...

Comment: de esa forma funciona y ya no se desborda pero solo reemplaza la primera vocal de la cadena con el espacio y las demas vocales no

Comment: @fixbala Prueba de nuevo porque sí las reemplaza todas.

Comment: es verdad quitandole el decremento al caso base ya toma la cadena completa !

Comment: @Lobos si asi funciono con toda la cadena , ya queda listo el metodo recusivo y queda funcionando gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema se genera aquí:

```
return sacarConsonantes(i++, aux=' ', array);
```

siempre tendrás el valor de 0 para la variable i, realiza un incremento antes de enviar a el método el nuevo valor de la variable, de esta forma:

```
return sacarConsonantes(++i, aux=' ', array);
```

la diferencia aquí es que incrementa la variable en el momento, y usando i++ se incrementa posteriormente posteriormente pero al llamar el método conserva el valor de 0.

Si deseas reemplazar la consonantes te sugiero un método más corto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cad="santi";     
    String string = sacarConsonantes(cad);
    System.out.println(string);            
}

 public static String sacarConsonantes(String cadena) {  
     cadena = cadena.replaceAll( "[aeiouAEIOáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]", "" );
     return cadena;
}
```